# Grouping HashBasedTable entries based on DateTime row

Tags: java, algorithm, datetime, grouping, hashtable

I have a HashBasedTable (`com.google.common.collect.HashBasedTable`) in the following format: `Table<DateTime, C, V>`. `DateTime` is coming from `org.joda.time.DateTime`.

I would like to group the entries based on a specific time interval. For example, if entry A and B are within 100ms of each other, I would like to group them together on the same row. I have the option to do this on insertion as well as post-insertion during processing. How should I do this in the most efficient way?

Reference links:

https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html

https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html

Comment: *"within 100ms of each other"* What if times are `6080 ms`, `6150 ms`, and `6220 ms`? #1 and #2 are within 100ms of each other, and #2 and #3 are within 100ms of each other, but #1 and #3 are more than 100ms from each other. How should they be grouped?

Comment: Normally, you wouldn't group "within 100ms of each other", but create 100ms wide time slots, by truncating the time to a 100ms boundary, and then collecting the data in an `Map<DateTime, List<V>>`, so all values falling into the same time slot are added to the list for that time slot.

Comment: @ole-v-v: `Table` type: `com.google.common.collect.HashBasedTable` and `DateTime` type: `org.joda.time.DateTime`

To address the first comment @andreas: while inserting `6150`, I would group it with `6080`, and for `6220` since that's more than 100ms with respect to the first group (`6080`), I would separate that out.

To address the second comment @andreas: yes that could sound like a more sound approach. Let's say I could round it up to the nearest 100ms.

Comment: Is using Joda-Time a fixed requirement? Asking because Joda-Time has been succeeded by java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s an example.

```
    Table<DateTime, String, String> yourTable = // your HashBasedTable;
    Map<DateTime, List<Map<String, String>>> groupedRows = yourTable.rowMap()
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey().minusMillis(e.getKey().getMillisOfSecond() % 100),
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

In order to use a stream I first call `rowMap` to get a `Map<DateTime, Map<C, V>>`, which is streamable. The stream is of map entries. I group them by a the datetime truncated to nearest 100 milliseconds. The way I truncate: If the time is 6150 ms, `e.getKey().getMillisOfSecond() % 100` gives me the 50 ms, which I subtract to get 6100 ms. Thus all times from 6100 through 6199 milliseconds are grouped together. In the grouping I use a *downstream collector* to pick the values (the `Map<C, V>`s) out of the entries for the inner lists in the result.

Disclaimer: I haven’t got Guava/Google Core Libraries installed, so I haven’t tested everything.